# How can i login to this site with requests module in python based on the request headers i got from firebug tool?

Tags: php, python, html, post, python-requests

```
GET /some/home.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.10
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://10.10.10.10/some/lverify.php
Cookie: PHPSESSID=98gngotqd668112db9e5u2emo0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here is the html form

```
<form action="lverify.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Log in</legend>
<label for="login">Username</label>
<input id="user" class="uname" type="text" maxlength="55" name="user">
<div class="clear"></div>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input id="hotel_pwd" class="pwd" type="password" maxlength="25" name="pwd">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br>
<input class="button" type="Submit" value="Log in" style="margin: -20px 0 0 287px;" name="Submit">
</fieldset>
</form>


#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
payload = {'user': 'abc', 'pwd': '1234'}
r = requests.post("http://10.10.10.10/some/home.php", data=payload)

i am not unable to get it working
```

1. Need to the know the right systax to login to the site using requests module
2. Is there a way i login to this site from different system and take the phpsesid and use it to login from different system without directly login from the requests

Comment: You forgot to post 'Submit'

Comment: how and where on the code should i include it , it will help you could give example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests

payload = { 'user': 'abc', 'pwd': '1234', 'Submit' : 'Log in' }  
r = requests.Session()  ## use this object for any POST or GET from now on ##
login = r.post("http://10.10.10.10/some/home.php", data=payload)
```

You should be able to log in now .
If not , try with 'User-Agent' and 'Referer' in the `headers`

Comment: I get error Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out  even with 'User-Agent' and 'Referer' in the headers

login = r.post("http://10.10.10.10/some/home.php", data=payload, headers=header)

Comment: Can you give me the actual url ?

Comment: Can you reach the url with a web browser ?

Comment: It is a local url    http://192.168.200.53/tool/home.php    ,,, Yes with with web browser i can.

Comment: Since i cant access the url, i cant do much more .  I suggest trying with different perameters ( headers, cookies, get / post / put, etc ) and see what works

Comment: Thanks your code actually works. the system from which i was coding did not have access to that IP. Now i tried with same system from which web browser access was there and it works. my bad i should have checked it correctly.